# Update x axis and Append new data when d3 graph is zoomed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am writing codes using `d3.behavior.zoom()` for graph zoom in and out. My codes and graph are almost the same as [this] (https://jsfiddle.net/lszhou2115/npzjLng9/11/)

You could notice that we have `update` and `reset` function. 
`Update` helps add newdata to d3 and `reset` helps reset the zoom.

With the help of `d3.behavior.zoom()`, we can now zoom in and out and move the lines. The updating process works totally "fine" when graph is not zoomed.

However, if the graph is zoomed, when `Update` is clicked, the x axis is always reset. (The graph is not reset but moving backwards.) I think the most related block is this:

```
function Update() {
//....
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
//....
}
```

I think there are two solutions,

- One is when graph is zoomed, just append new line/data to current line. In this case, we do NOT need to update the scale and the graph does not move backward.
- Another one is that allow the graph to move backwards when updating, but the x axis is updated without resetting.

Question: how to implement the two solutions?

I prefer the first solution, but the second one is also acceptable. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

=================== Update =========================

For the first solution, I have partly implemented it. Without zooming, new lines could be append to existing lines. But when graph is moved or zoomed, then the new line is not appended to the right place, here is the new [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uEwNgREFNrZ60e5HyiMv?p=preview) for the first solution.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question: how to implement the two solutions? @LarsKotthoff

Comment: For the first solution, don't call `svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);` if the zoom scale is something other than 1.

Comment: thanks@LarsKotthoff   ,then how can I update the axis in the right way?

Comment: It would be done automatically in the zoom handler function as long as you update the scale.

Comment: Sorry, do not really understand. So I commented the code `svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)` you mentioned, and leave all zoom codes unchanged like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/uEwNgREFNrZ60e5HyiMv?p=preview), but it still does not work in the right way even the scale is updated via `xScale.domain(xOrig)` @LarsKotthoff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100517/discussion-between-longsheng-zhou-and-lars-kotthoff).